# how to combine list of list in python into a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list here

```
arg_list = ['arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4']

value_list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[3,5,2,4]]
```

I'd like to convert this into a list of dict objects

```
[{'arg1':1,'arg2':2,'arg3':3,'arg4':4},{'arg1':5,'arg2':6,'arg3':7,'arg4':8}....etc]
```

How can i get this done in the most pythonic fashion?

Comment: What "unpythonic" way are you doing it now?

Answer (score 6):

```
In [3]: [dict(zip(arg_list, e)) for e in value_list]
Out[3]:
[{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3, 'arg4': 4},
 {'arg1': 5, 'arg2': 6, 'arg3': 7, 'arg4': 8},
 {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5, 'arg3': 2, 'arg4': 4}]
```